# Return local variables without setting them global

Tags: python

Im learning about functions now and I totally see the usefulness of the concept.

However some of its logic still escapes me.

I have different variables some passed to the function some locally created. 
What I notice is that only the passed vars get returned and can get printed when the function was called.

c for example is locally created but can be printed outside. Except if i set it global inside the function, but I also read that this should be avoided.

Im not sure if im understanding functions right but shouldnt a local function be able to be returned without setting it global?

```
a = 345
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
import numpy as np

def return_func(a, b):
#    global a
#    global b
#    global c

    a = ("asd")
    b = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
    c = 10

    return a, b, c

return_func()    

print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
```

Comment: What is `array_return()`?

Comment: sry that should be return_func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return of your function to local variables:

```
a, b, c = return_func(a, b)
```

Of course, here, the original values of `a` and `b` are changed because the assignment changes them.

Be aware also of the names of your functions, there is no `array_return` in this question.

Comment: Yes the change was intended. 

Why exactly do I assign the vars to the function when i call it though?

Comment: Because the variables only exist inside that function. They are not the same as the variables outside (except if using `global`). Once you go out of the function, the variables don't exist. But you got return values from your function that you can assign to new variables (they don't have to have the same name).